# Solutions to a special confluent Vandermonde system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-functions, interpolation, matrix-inverse

Consider the polynomial $P(X) =\prod_{i=1}^k (X-x_i)^s$ and let $M$ be the corresponding confluent Vandermonde matrix. Concretely, here is what I mean by that. Define
$$
M^{(0)} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
x_1 & x_2 & \cdots &x_k\\
x^2_1 & x^2_2 & \cdots &x^2_k\\
\vdots\\
x^{ks-1}_1 & x^{ks-1}_2 & \cdots &x^{ks-1}_k
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is the $ks\times k$ Vandermonde matrix. Let $D=\sum_i \partial/\partial x_i$ be an operator. Define
$$
M^{(n)} = \frac{1}{n!}D^n M^{(0)}
$$
Then $M=(M^{(0)}, M^{(1)}, \cdots, M^{(s-1)})$ which is $ks\times ks$. With that definition, now here is my question:

> Is there a clean formula for the solution $F$ of the system $MF=B$? Equivalently, is $M^{-1}$ known in terms of, say, symmetric functions? For all intents and purposes we can define $M^{(n)}=D^n M^{(0)}$ instead (as confluent Vandermonde is sometimes defined) if it helps.